# How to remove v-btn background in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I remove the background behind the button when I hover or clicking on the v-btn?

I try to set ripple to false, but still have background. I can't find the css does this background.

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.15/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.15/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid class="pa-0">
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
              <p>Normal</p>
            </v-col>
  
            <v-col cols="12" sm="3">
              <v-btn ripple="false" icon color="pink">
                <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-col>
  
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the background when click (ripple features) , you missing the bind annotation, you are passing the **string** instead of **false** value. So put the ":" before **ripple** will do the job.

However, to do with the hover background things,  you need to do some hack in css. I'm writing this in scss, you can follow the idea

```
<v-btn :ripple="false" icon color="pink" id="no-background-hover">
  <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
 </v-btn>


<style lang="scss">
#no-background-hover::before {
   background-color: transparent !important; <= can set to any color you want
}
</style>
```

the code above is only set to that specific button with id `"no-background-hover"` only, if you want this to happen to every other button. Then here is the class of that button, you can change your css query selector to the class level you need

```
<button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default pink--text" id="no-background"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-heart theme--light"></i></span></button>
```

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for an answer to this question for some time, I applied a hacked solution from here, but it has visual effects, Thank God I found a property that is responsible for this. You need to add a "**plain**" property to the button like this:

```
<v-btn fab large plain><v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon></v-btn>
```

This was made a deal for me.
Vuetify guide saying: **plain buttons have a lower baseline opacity that reacts to hover and focus.**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: this also changes the button text to a bit lighter, which changes to original color on hover; which might be undesirable for few.

Answer (score 4):

To take out the background on v-btn, you can use the following css property,

```
<style scoped>
.v-btn::before {
  background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

to remove the ripple effect, you have to use v-ripple,

```
<v-btn v-ripple="false" icon>
<v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `plain` prop should do the trick. According the description it will remove "the default background change applied when hovering over a button":
[image]

*Wanted to simplify the previous answer, but the edit queue was full.

Comment: Legend this worked like a charm